# What is the difference between Electric Vehicle Charging Infrastructure (EVCI) and Electric Vehicle Supply Equipment (EVSE)?

Tags: charging, electric-vehicle

I'm just getting involved in the EV charging in a professional capacity, and I'm having trouble finding an authoritative answer on the difference between supply equipment and charging infrastructure. It seems clear that the latter is intended to include *more* than the former, but it's not clear to me where the line is drawn.

What things are definitely included in EVSE?

What things are definitely only included in EVCI?

What other things are borderline?

Does anyone know of an authoritative reference to what is and isn't in each category?

Answer (score 1):

EVSE is defined in the [National Electric Code](https://www.nfpa.org/codes-and-standards/7/0/nfpa-70):

> Equipment for plug-in charging, including the ungrounded, grounded, and equipment grounding conductors, and the electric vehicle connectors, attachment plugs, personnel protection system, and all other fittings, devices, power outlets, or apparatus installed specifically for the purpose of transferring energy between the premises wiring and the electric vehicle.

EVCI is not a standard term, just an abbreviation used to generally refer to "all the chargers." Perhaps the best definition can be found in the [Bipartisan Infrastructure Law (Section 11129)](https://www.congress.gov/117/bills/hr3684/BILLS-117hr3684enr.pdf):

> Electric vehicle charging infrastructure installed using funds provided under this title shall provide, at a minimum — (A) non-proprietary charging connectors that meet applicable industry safety standards; and (B) open access to payment methods that are available to all members of the public to ensure secure, convenient, and equal access to the electric vehicle charging infrastructure that shall not be limited by membership to a particular payment provider.